# Difference between string.empty and string[0] == '\0'

Tags: c++, string

Suppose we have a string

```
std::string str; // some value is assigned
```

What is the difference between `str.empty()`  and `str[0] == '\0'`?

Comment: `std::string` does not need to end with '\0'

Comment: @appleapple: `str[str.size()]` is always `'\0'` (as discussed below).

Comment: yes, (since c++11)

Comment: The main difference is for strings like `std::string str{"\0foo", 4}`.  `std::string`, unlike C-style strings, may have embedded NULs.

Answer (score 93):

#### C++11 and beyond

`string_variable[0]` is required to return the null character if the string is empty. That way there is no undefined behavior and the comparison still works if the string is truly empty. However you *could* have a string that starts with a null character (`"\0Hi there"`) which returns `true` even though it is not empty. If you really want to know if it's empty, use `empty()`.

---

#### Pre-C++11

The difference is that if the string is empty then `string_variable[0]` has undefined behavior; There is no index 0 unless the string is `const`-qualified.  If the string *is* `const` qualified then it will return a null character.

`string_variable.empty()` on the other hand returns true if the string is empty, and false if it is not; the behavior won't be undefined.

---

#### Summary

`empty()` is meant to check whether the string/container is empty or not. It works on all containers that provide it and using `empty` clearly states your intent - which means a lot to people reading your code (including you).

Comment: `empty()` also works with `std::u16string` without requiring changes to the code

Comment: can you give a quote from the standard that `string[0]` is ok when `string.size() == 0`? sounds very not C++is

Comment: Just nitpicking here: Pre C++11, I think that the behavior is still well-defined if the string is const-qualified, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/, quote: "If pos is equal to the string length and the string is const-qualified, the function returns a reference to a null character ('\0')."

Comment: @rainer That only happens on a `const` string.

Comment: @NathanOliver: that's why I said I was nitpicking ;). (Also, I mentioned the const-qualified part.)

Comment: @rainer Added that to the pre C++11 part.

Comment: Also, there may be a tiny performance difference; I believe in favour of `empty()`. Typical implementation of `empty()` is one ptr comparison, while `str[0]` needs to actually dereference the pointer and look if there is the zero character.

Comment: @user3013179 We had a big discussion about thisa few months back and the outcome was all `operator[]` needs to do is return the character at the index provided.  This is because there is a precondition that the index must less than or equal to the size of the string.  Not sure if one is a couple cycles faster or not but it really isn't something I would worry about.

Comment: @NathanOliver: there is difference, check Oberon's answer.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I did talk about that.  Hopefully the edit makes it more clear about that.

Comment: I think this answer is poorly worded, because it's encouraging the use of a potentially-confusing construct. There is no good reason to use `str[0] == '\0'` instead of `str.empty()`. The second explicitly indicates its intent. The first one somewhat obscures what the programmer was trying to accomplish, and in some cases it won't return the expected result (as you noted, if a string may contain embedded `\0` characters, then the two checks don't have the same semantics. I would definitely not lead with "they will both work" under C++11.

Comment: @JasonR Edited it some more.  What do you think?

Comment: @NathanOliver sounds better to me.

Comment: You can't "cause" undefined behaviour!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the edit.  You can invoke it though right?

Comment: @NathanOliver: No! You can only have a program whose behaviour is undefined. That is, the program has undefined behaviour. At best you could "cause a program to have undefined behaviour". Of course we all just say "it causes undefined behaviour" (including me from time to time, I'm sure), but it's Tuesday evening and I needed to find something to nitpick :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That makes sense(not the Tuesday night nitpick fest but the explanation)  Thanks again for the explanation and the edit and have fun picking the nit. :-)

Comment: @NathanOliver: \o/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Actually, it's a particular execution of a program whose behavior is either defined or undefined.  "undefined behavior" is only triggered if (not when) the control flow of the program takes it through an operation or construct whose behavior is undefined.  Weirdly, the program can start misbehaving before it gets to that point, but only if it does get there.  Another execution of the same program on different input that causes a branch around the problematic operation can be perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @BenVoigt And so the nitpicker become the nitpickee!

Comment: @BenVoigt But I think it is reasonable to say that "a *program's* behaviour is undefined" if there exists any execution on valid input with undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 38):

Since C++11 it is guaranteed that `str[str.size()] == '\0'`. This means that if a string is empty, then `str[0] == '\0'`. But a C++ string has an explicit length field, meaning it can contain embedded null characters.

E.g. for `std::string str("\0ab", 3)`, `str[0] == '\0'` but `str.empty()` is false.

Besides, `str.empty()` is more readable than `str[0] == '\0'`.

Comment: I like this answer because it mentions that `std::string` _isn't_ (required to be) null-terminated. I think. Or at least that not every null is its termination.

Comment: Since the comments have been destroyed without notification, I shall have to say it again (thanks for that guys): @QPaysTaxes Just so that you and other readers are aware (you said "I think" which suggests you are unsure), the correct part of your comment is the last part. Not the first part, which is not.

Comment: @Lightness Your old comments were incredibly vague; I couldn't tell what "end" you meant. This version is much more helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Other answers here are 100% correct. I just want to add three more notes:

`empty` is generic (every STL container implements this function) while `operator []` with `size_t` only works with string objects and array-like containers. when dealing with generic STL code, `empty` is preferred.

also, `empty` is pretty much self explanatory while `=='\0'` is not very much.
when it's 2AM and you debug your code, would you prefer see `if(str.empty())` or `if(str[0] == '\0')`? 
if only functionality matters, we would all write in vanilla assembly.

there is also a performance penalty involved. `empty` is usually implemented by comparing the size member of the string to zero, which is very cheap, easy to inline etc. comparing against the first character might be more heavy. first of all, since all strings implement *short string optimization*, the program first has to ask if the string is in "short mode" or "long mode". branching - worse performance. if the string is long, dereferencing it may be costly if the string was "ignored" for some time and the dereference itself may cause a cache-fault which is costly.

Comment: Never think about optimization on such a low level unless it is actually slow.  Performance doesn't matter unless it's in the innerst loop of a long running program. (premature optimization is an illness which is more frequent under C/C++-programmers imho) - also: `if(str[0] == '\0')` is perfectly valid if I'm explicitly looking for `\0`/ empty NULL-terminated string and not an empty string object (yes, unlikely but possible)

Answer (score 6):

empty() is not implemented as looking for the existence of a null character at position 0, its simply

```
bool empty() const
{
    return size() == 0 ;
}
```

Which could be different

Answer (score 4):

Also, beware of the functions you'll use if you use C++ 11 or later version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    std::string str("\0ab", 3);

    std::cout << "The size of str is " << str.size() << " bytes.\n";
    std::cout << "The size of str is " << str.length() << " long.\n";
    std::cout << "The size of str is " << std::strlen(str.c_str()) << " long.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

will return

> The size of str is 3 bytes.
>
> The size of str is 3 long.
>
> The size of str is 0 long.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know the difference between `str.empty() and str[0] == '\0'`. Lets follow the example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string str, str2; //both string is empty
str2 = "values"; //assigning a value to 'str2' string
str2[0] = '\0'; //assigning '\0' to str2[0], to make sure i have '\0' at 0 index

if(str.empty()) cout << "str is empty" << endl;
else cout << "str contains: " << str << endl;

if(str2.empty()) cout << "str2 is empty" << endl;
else cout << "str2 contains: " << str2 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
str is empty
str2 contains: alues
```

`str.empty()` will let you know the string is empty or not and `str[0] == '\0'` will let you know your strings 0 index contains `'\0'` or not. Your string variables 0 index contains `'\0'` doesn't mean that your string is empty. Yes, only once it can be possible when your string length is 1 and your string variables 0 index contains `'\0'`. That time you can say that, its an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

C++ string has the concept of whether it is empty or not.  If the string is empty then str[0] is undefined. Only if C++ string has size >1, str[0] is defined.

str[i] == '\0' is a concept of the C-string style.  In the implementation of C-string, the last character of the string is '\0' to mark the end of a C-string.
For C-string you usually have to 'remember' the length of your string with a separate variable.  In C++ String you can assign any position with '\0'.

Just a code segment to play with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char str[5] = "abc";
   cout << str << " length: " << strlen(str) << endl;
   cout << "char at 4th position: " << str[3] << "|" << endl;
   cout << "char at 5th position: " << str[4] << "|" << endl;
   str[4]='X'; // this is OK, since Cstring is just an array of char!
   cout << "char at 5th position after assignment: " << str[4] << "|" << endl;
   string cppstr("abc");
   cppstr.resize(3);
   cout << "cppstr: " << cppstr << " length: " << cppstr.length() << endl;
   cout << "char at 4th position:" << cppstr[3] << endl;
   cout << "char at 401th positon:" << cppstr[400] << endl;
   // you should be getting segmentation fault in the
   // above two lines! But this may not happen every time.

   cppstr[0] = '\0';
   str[0] = '\0';
   cout << "After zero the first char. Cstring: " << str << " length: " << strlen(str) << " | C++String: " << cppstr << " length: " << cppstr.length() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

### On my machine the output:

```
abc length: 3
char at 4th position: |
char at 5th position: |
char at 5th position after assignment: X|
cppstr: abc length: 3
char at 4th position:
char at 401th positon:?
After zero the first char. Cstring:  length: 0 | C++String: bc length: 3
```