# Do std::strings end in '\0' when initialized with a string literal?

Tags: c++, string, null-terminated, subscript-operator

I know string objects aren't null terminated but why should this work?

```
std::string S("Hey");
for(int i = 0; S[i] != '\0'; ++i)
   std::cout << S[i];
```

So the constructor copies the null terminator as well, but does not increment the length? Why does it bother?

Comment: `std::string` does not smell like C.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725183/difference-between-string-empty-and-string0-0/39725242

Comment: I reopened the question because OP knew about `std::string` is not null terminated but confused about the behavior of `std::string::operator[]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So the constructor copies the null terminator as well, but does not increment the length?

As you've known that `std::string` doesn't contain the null character (and it doesn't copy the null character here).

The point is that you're using `std::basic_string::operator[]`. According to C++11, [`std::basic_string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) will return a null character when specified index is equivalent to `size()`.

> If `pos == size()`, a reference to the character with value `CharT()` (the null character) is returned.
>
> For the first (non-const) version, the behavior is undefined if this character is modified to any value other than `charT()`.

Answer (score 10):

`std::string` stores its data internally in the form of a null-terminated C-string, but in normal usage does not allow you to access the null terminator.

For example, if I assign the value "Hello, World!" to a string, the internal buffer will look like this:

```
std::string myString("Hello, World!");

// Internal Buffer...
// [ H | e | l | l | o | , |   | W | o | r | d | ! | \0 ]
//                                                   ^ Null terminator.
```

In this example, the null terminator was NOT copied from the end of the string literal, but added internally by `std::string`.

As @songyuanyao mentions in his answer, the result of this is that `myString[myString.size()];` returns `'\0'`.

So why does `std::string` assign a null terminator to the end of the string? It certainly doesn't have to support one, because you can add `'\0'` to a string and it is included in the string:

```
std::string myString;
myString.size();              // 0
myString.push_back('\0');
myString.size();              // 1
```

The reason for this behavior is to support the [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function. The `c_str()` function is required to return a null-terminated `const char *`. The most efficient way to do this is to simply return a pointer to the internal buffer, but in order to do that **the internal buffer must include a null terminator character at the end of the string**. Since C++11, strings are *required* to include the null terminator to support this.

P.S. While not strictly part of your question, it should be pointed out that the loop from your question might NOT return a full string if your string includes null characters:

```
std::string S("Hey");
S.push_back('\0');
S.append("Jude");

for(int i = 0; S[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    std::cout << S[i];

// Only "Hey" is printed!
```

Answer (score 0):

- **`std::string` Overload:** The `std::string` class has a special way to store its length, so it doesn't need null-termination like C-style strings. You can use `S[i]` to access characters directly, and the loop works without `'\0'`.
- **Efficient Handling:** The `std::string` constructor doesn't add a null terminator when creating the string because it uses a smarter length management method. This approach is more efficient for handling and manipulating strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).